# Trigger knowing the event type dynamically

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

I have mostly the same code for a trigger that occurs before a `INSERT` or `UPDATE`,
and instead of creating 2 triggers, is there any way to know the type of event occurring dynamically inside the trigger ?

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UpsertClientLog() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE action_type VARCHAR(255);
BEGIN
  IF (event == 'INSERT') THEN
    action_type = 'Create'
  ELSE 
    action_type = 'Update'
  END IF;

  -- Same code from here on out ..
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER UPSERT_CLIENT_LOG BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON client
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE UpsertClientLog();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [special variable `TO_OP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html):

> `TG_OP`
>
> Data type text; a string of `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `TRUNCATE` telling for which operation the trigger was fired.